# Downloading a web page and searching a text with python

Tags: python, search, text, web

I'm trying to scrape specific text from a website.  Because I'm new in Python, I find it difficult to scrape a text with a single script, so I used this code first:

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmltext = urllib.urlopen("https://io.winmasters.com/Feeds/api/event /282576?lang=el").read()

data = htmltext
soup =  BeautifulSoup(data)
f = open('/Desktop/text.txt', 'w')
f.write(data)
f.close()`
```

and next I'm trying to write a script for searching the text and print specific words.

```
with open("/Desktop/text.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for part in line.split():
            if "odds=" in part:
                print part
```

but the search script doesn't return the text I'm searching for.  Any suggestions please?

Comment: There is a space in the url you try to open. https://io.winmasters.com/Feeds/api/event%20/282576?lang=el should be https://io.winmasters.com/Feeds/api/event/282576?lang=el

Comment: What does the script returns you and what are you searching for ?

Comment: Good spot. Furthermore, the URL seems to return JSON, which is very convenient, and is easily parsed with the Python `json` library using `loads`. `odds` is one of the keys in the JSON, so it would be straightforward to find all values.

Comment: Is there any reason you have a `import requests` there, then use `urllib.urlopen` anyway - seems a wasted opportunity to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want the values associated with the `odds` key, without any context at all, you could simply do the following:

```
import urllib
from json import loads # JSON parser

jsontext = urllib.urlopen("https://io.winmasters.com/Feeds/api/event/282576?lang=el").read()
data = loads(jsontext) # Parse the JSON

odds = [[b['odds'] for b in a['children']] for a in data['children']]
```

The nested list comprehension takes advantage of the structure of the data. An advantage of using the data structure is that you can do quite rich analytics without too much effort. If you wanted other info in addition to the odds then this would probably better implemented as a nested `for`-loop.

Comment: thanx man for the help.  I just replace "from json import loads" with "import simplejson   because i was receiving some errors.

in the last line how can i insert another filter? e.x from Children,  Name,  odds

Comment: If the code solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer. :-)

Comment: If you want some additional information, if it's in the same level as the `odds` data (like maxStake, name, bookmakerId'), then it's simply a case of adding those keys to the list comprehension: `odds = [[[b['name'], b['maxStake'], b['odds']] for b in a['children']] for a in data['children']]`. It's really worth taking time to understand the JSON data structure, as once you have parsed it all the data is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import sys
from bs4 import Beautiful Soup
import mechanize

def viewPage(url):
    browser=mechanize.Browser()
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.addheaders=[('user-agent','MozillaMozilla/5.0')]
    page=browser.open(url)
    source_code=page.read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(source_code)
    info=soup.findAll("insert what you want to locate")
    print(info)
viewPage("www.xkcd.com")
```

I have a program that when you choose a webpage it reads off all the links, chooses one at random and goes to it, doing the same.  It basically crawls across the interweb.  The code above is a modified excerpt.